# How do I create a nested calculation in DAX?

Tags: excel, dax

I have average amount of components which I need to calculate for each component in order to calculate the average for the whole.

I do not have the base data from which the averages are calculated. This is for a call center calculation.

Each grouping has multiple sub-types. The averages are the calculation within these sub types. I need to find the average for the group.

I have determined a calculation to do this but do not know how to do it in DAX.

```
(
( (avg_time_a + avg_time_b) * #calls ) +    :: for Type A, Group X, Interval Y
( (avg_time_a + avg_time_b) * #calls ) +    :: for Type B, Group X, Interval Y
( (avg_time_a + avg_time_b) * #calls ) +    :: for Type C, Group X, Interval Y
( (avg_time_a + avg_time_b) * #calls ) )    :: for Type ...
/ Sum(#calls)
```

I believe I have to use Earlier but I've not been able to figure it out.

above

```
    Column Labels   
    North   
Row Labels  frct calls  avg handletime
4/13/2019 20:00 52.5    295.71
4/13/2019 20:30 39.13333333 347.13
4/13/2019 21:00 44.8    164.55
4/13/2019 21:30 29.2    444.69
4/13/2019 22:00 24.3    239.43
4/13/2019 22:30 24.16666667 165.42
4/13/2019 23:00 16.26666667 549.83
```

Ignore the frct calls. I have that. The handletime grouped by interval (row) and Group (column) is the result I'm seeking.

I did attempt this:

```
=CALCULATE(
           (SUM( [AverageACWTimeInSeconds])+SUM([AverageTalkTimeInSeconds]))*SUM([NumberOfInteractions]),
           ALLEXCEPT( IO_VolumeForecastStats, IO_VolumeForecastStats[IntervalStartEDT], IO_VolumeForecastStats[WorkgroupName])
  )
```

... however it summed all of avg_time_x and multiplied by all calls instead of looking at each Skill type data and processing one at a time.

Comment: avg_time_a avg_time_b #calls Type Group Interval
0 0 0 A North 4/13/2019 20:00
0 0 0 B North 4/13/2019 20:00
23 214 0.333333333 C North 4/13/2019 20:00
23 89 0.333333333 D North 4/13/2019 20:00
23 214 0.1 E North 4/13/2019 20:00
23 89 0.1 F North 4/13/2019 20:00
0 0 1 G North 4/13/2019 20:00
0 0 1 H North 4/13/2019 20:00
17.05263158 340.6842105 3.3 I North 4/13/2019 20:00
22.91666667 287.4166667 4 J North 4/13/2019 20:00

Comment: Attempted this but it's summing all avg_time_a and avg_time_b and multiplying by all calls

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that this question was such a mess.

To use EARLIER() I had to create a key field unique to each row. I did this by CONCATENATE() Group & Type & Interval so each row had a unique key value for Earlier to reference. I also had to create it as a calculated field and not a measure.

To resolve the first part I had to first create a calculated field that would calculate on a per Type basis the ( (avg_time_a + avg_time_b) * #calls ) and sum them for all types. To do this:

```
=CALCULATE(
           (SUM( [avg_time_a])+SUM([avg_time_b]))*SUM([#calls]),
           ALLEXCEPT( MyTable, MyTable[Interval], MyTable[Group]),
           FILTER( MyTable, MyTable[skill interval id]=Earlier(MyTable[skill interval id] ) )
  )
```

Once I had this field with a sum I could divide it my the number of calls.

I'm still iffy on using row context but I keep learning a bit at a time.